# How to limit Chrome extension content script to a specific content types?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to make content script injected only if document's content type matches specific pattern? Actually, my goal is much simpler: I need my content script injected to HTML documents **only** (for now, it's injected in XML docs as well). Content scripts must be injected at "document_start".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to a similar problem and solved it in the following way.

Instead of limiting variety  of documents where a content script is injected, based on documents' `Content-Type`, I decided to inject the script into all documents, but execute it in proper ones only.

This is done by analysing `document.xmlVersion` and `document.doctype` properties:

- `document.doctype` must be not `null` in an HTML document;
- `document.xmlVersion` must be not `null` in an XML document;

So, it is easy to use either of them to distinguish one type from another and "bind" all necessary script stuff only when appropriate. In particular, one can inject small script loader, which will load additional, possibly heavy stuff, conditionally.

Chrome does not still provide any means for limiting script injection by document type.

Answer (score 0):

The most robust way to do this is via [`chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.webRequest.html#event-onHeadersReceived), which allows you to query and retain response header information (including `Content-Type`).  Unfortunately, this API is not currently available in stable releases of Chrome.  (You can use the experimental API in current verisons of Chrome, but you will not be able to publish extensions that use it.)

One possible solution for you is to determine whether or not the injected document is being treated by Chrome as XML.  (And if it is, stop processing the document.)  A hack to accomplish this is to check if `document.getElementById('webkit-xml-viewer-source-xml')` is `null`.  This element part of Chrome/webkit's XML viewer.

Comment: What if your content script adds an event listener to wait for the document to be loaded before performing an action?  For example, `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ do.stuff() };`.

Comment: This is what I should avoid, my script must be executed first (before document is loaded).

Comment: I see.  In that case, I have no other recommendations.  Good luck.